# I got the following when I did poetry add playwright. How Do I fix?

Tags: playwright, python-poetry

**I ran:**

```
poetry add playwright
```

The System I am using is MAC-OS-Monterrey

Version = "0.1.0"

**And got this error:**

```
Using version ^1.24.1 for playwright

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  AssertionError

  

  at /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/mixology/incompatibility.py:111 in __str__
      107│         )
      108│ 
      109│     def __str__(self):
      110│         if isinstance(self._cause, DependencyCause):
    → 111│             assert len(self._terms) == 2
      112│ 
      113│             depender = self._terms[0]
      114│             dependee = self._terms[1]
      115│             assert depender.is_positive()
```

This is the error message obtained when I ran the command. Can some one please guide me?

I really need this to work as my docker container requires this library to work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Seems out of scope for StackOverfllow. Ask Poetry team directly. And you will need to provide more details than this, such as the version of Poetry being used.